# Is the set satisfying $-1 \leq Re(z) \leq 5$ closed?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I want to prove if such set is closed. We define for $z = x+iy$ in $\mathbb{C},$
$$\mathcal{O} := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: -1 \leq Re(z) \leq 5\} = \{(x,y) : x \in [-1,5], y \in (-\infty,\infty)\}.$$
Recall that a set is closed if and only if its complement is open. It is easy to see that 
$$\mathcal{O}^c : = \{(x,y) : x \in (-\infty,-1) \cup (5,\infty), y = 0\}.$$
and $\mathcal{O}^c$ is indeed open, for instance, given $\epsilon > 0$, and $x \in \mathcal{O}^c $, we have that 
$$(x -\epsilon, x + \epsilon)\subset \mathcal{O}^c.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to prove that the *complement* of $\mathcal O$ is open, which can be verified directly by taking an element of that complement and proving that a small disk around it is also included in the complement of $\mathcal O.$

We have

$$\mathcal{O}^c = \{(x,y) : x \in (-\infty,-1) \cup (5,\infty)\}.$$

Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary point in $\mathcal O^c,$ then either $x<-1$ or $x>5.$ In the former case let $\epsilon=\frac{x+1}2,$ in the latter let $\epsilon=\frac{x-5}2.$ In both cases the open ball $B((x,y),\epsilon)$ avoids $\mathcal O,$ i.e., it is contained in $\mathcal O^c.$

Slightly more sophisticated, but shorter: in the product space $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ we see that $\mathcal O$ is defined as the product of two closed subsets of $\mathbb R,$ namely a closed interval and $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: This means that the set is indeed closed?

Comment: Yes, it is closed.

Comment: I modified my solution. does make sense now?

Comment: Not entirely. The complement $\mathcal{O}^c$ is actually $\{(x,y) : x \in (-\infty,-1) \cup (5,\infty)\}$ without any conditions on $y.$

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it a lot